# payment after form submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, paypal

I have a form to create a new Event. After creating the new event, I want to post form info to PayPal PayFlow and send the user to the paypal website to complete payment. My inexperienced guess is to make an after_create callback to render a separate view to post the paypal payflow form information. But it doesn't seem like the right solution.

Can you suggest a more 'Rails way' to do this?

Here are more details about the PayPal Payflow process:
I pass some params

```
`curl https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com -kd "TRXTYPE=S&AMT=23.45&CURRENCY=USD&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5"`
```

and receive a secure token
        `RESULT=0&RESPMSG=Approved&SECURETOKEN[25]=Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA==&SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5`

Then I can post the values to paypal like so:

```
<body>
  <form method="post" action="https://payflowlink.paypal.com">
    <input type=hidden value="Fj+1AFUWft0+I0CUFOKh5WA==" name=SECURETOKEN/>
    <input type=hidden value="9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4c5" name=SECURETOKENID/>
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this link: [Rails, How to submit PayPal requests from controller, instead of a form, URL encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929716/rails-how-to-submit-paypal-requests-from-controller-instead-of-a-form-url-enc)

Because I am using Payflow, I added a bit more code to use secure tokens.

`events_controller.rb`

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @event.save!
            format.html { redirect_to @event.send_to_paypal }
            format.json { render json: @event, status: :created, location: @event }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

`event.rb`

```
def send_to_paypal
    token = UUIDTools::UUID.random_create.to_s
    response = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(`curl https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com -kd "#{GATEWAY.to_param}&TRXTYPE=S&AMT=23.45&CURRENCY=USD&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=#{token}"`)

    if response['SECURETOKENID'] != token || response['RESULT'] != "0" || response['SECURETOKEN'].blank?
        raise StandardError, response['RESPMSG']
    else
        URI.encode("https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com?MODE=test&SECURETOKENID=#{token}&SECURETOKEN=#{response['SECURETOKEN']}")
    end
end
```

GATEWAY is a config constant with my payflow gateway parameters (.

I initially got some vague errors submitting test data in payflowlink.paypal.com. Similar to this link, [PayPal's Payflow Gateway SDK Example not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171166/paypals-payflow-gateway-sdk-example-not-working) This was caused by passing the PARMLIST in the `URI.encode(...)`. After taking PARMLIST out and adding `MODE=test` then everything worked as expected. Hopefully this helps other people using Payflow.